# Group Как обратиться выше к группе?

Tags: powershell

Объясняю. Я сортирую таблицу по датам (убираю одинаковые даты). В тоже время я хочу видеть то что я убрал и поместить в отдельное поле. В общем, показываю на рисунке.

```
$arr| group Login | foreach { $_.group | sort Date | select -first 1} | FT
```

Рис1 - это то что есть в массиве arr
Рис2 - это то что получается группировкой
Рис3 - это отсортированная таблица без одинаковых дат. Но красным справа хотелось бы видеть отдельное поле, в которой будут данные из вышестоящей Group (но не знаю как обратиться к Group)

[image: Рис1]

[image: Рис2]

[image: Рис3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PS C:\Users\alHaos> $arr = @"
andrey.mukhin              29.01.2021 15:40           29.01.2021
andrey.mukhin              29.01.2021 15:50           29.01.2021
aleksandr.shubin           29.01.2021 15:00           29.01.2021
konstantin.lysov           29.01.2021 15:55           29.01.2021
Igor.Pekishev              29.01.2021 14:00           29.01.2021
polina.proseczkaya         29.01.2021 15:08           29.01.2021
nikita.ustrikovifirtlabs.ru06.11.2020 14:15           06.11.2020
mariya.zhilyak             06.11.2020 02:32           06.11.2020
"@ -split "`r`n" | ForEach-Object {
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    Login    = $_.SubString(0, 27).Trim()
    DateFull = [datetime]::Parse($_.SubString(28, 16).Trim())
    Date     = [datetime]::Parse($_.SubString(54, 10))
  }
}

$arr | Group-Object Login, date | ForEach-Object {
    $login, $date = $_.name -split ", "
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      login = $login
      date = $date
      name2 = $_.Group
    }
}

login                       date               name2                                                                                                                                                         
-----                       ----               -----                                                                                                                                                         
andrey.mukhin               29.01.2021 0:00:00 {@{Login=andrey.mukhin; DateFull=09.01.2021 15:40:00; Date=29.01.2021 0:00:00}, @{Login=andrey.mukhin; DateFull=09.01.2021 15:50:00; Date=29.01.2021 0:00:00}}
aleksandr.shubin            29.01.2021 0:00:00 {@{Login=aleksandr.shubin; DateFull=09.01.2021 15:00:00; Date=29.01.2021 0:00:00}}                                                                            
konstantin.lysov            29.01.2021 0:00:00 {@{Login=konstantin.lysov; DateFull=09.01.2021 15:55:00; Date=29.01.2021 0:00:00}}                                                                            
Igor.Pekishev               29.01.2021 0:00:00 {@{Login=Igor.Pekishev; DateFull=09.01.2021 14:00:00; Date=29.01.2021 0:00:00}}                                                                               
polina.proseczkaya          29.01.2021 0:00:00 {@{Login=polina.proseczkaya; DateFull=09.01.2021 15:08:00; Date=29.01.2021 0:00:00}}                                                                          
nikita.ustrikovifirtlabs.ru 06.11.2020 0:00:00 {@{Login=nikita.ustrikovifirtlabs.ru; DateFull=06.11.2020 14:15:00; Date=06.11.2020 0:00:00}}                                                                 
mariya.zhilyak              06.11.2020 0:00:00 {@{Login=mariya.zhilyak; DateFull=06.11.2020 2:32:00; Date=06.11.2020 0:00:00}}                                                                               



PS C:\Users\alHaos>
```

Comment: Да, то что надо. Спасибо!